# Make Frequency histogram from list with tuple elements

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, distribution, frequency

I would like to make a word frequency distribution, with the words on the x-axis  and the frequency count on the y-axis.

I have the following list:

```
example_list = [('dhr', 17838), ('mw', 13675), ('wel', 5499), ('goed', 5080), 
                ('contact', 4506), ('medicatie', 3797), ('uur', 3792),
                ('gaan', 3473), ('kwam', 3463), ('kamer', 3447), 
                ('mee', 3278), ('gesprek', 2978)]
```

I tried to first convert it into a pandas DataFrame and then use the `pd.hist()` as in the example below, but I just can't figure it out and think it is actually straight forward but probably I'm missing something.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

word = []
frequency = []

for i in range(len(example_list)):
  word.append(example_list[i][0])
  frequency.append(example_list[i][1])


plt.bar(word, frequency, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't pass the `word`s into the [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) directly. However you could create an indices array for `bar` and then replace these indices with the `words` using [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

indices = np.arange(len(example_list))
plt.bar(indices, frequency, color='r')
plt.xticks(indices, word, rotation='vertical')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The `for`-loop to create `word` and `frequency` could also be replaced by a simple `zip` und list unpacking:

```
word, frequency = zip(*example_list)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, this was what i was looking for, also the zip is very usefull function:)

Comment: please define what libs you are using when calling "plt" and "np".

Comment: @biogeek These have been defined in the question already so I think it was a bit hard to downvote the answer for that. But to make the answer more self-contained I also included them in the code. Thanks for the comment. :)

Answer (score 11):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

example_list = [('dhr', 17838), ('mw', 13675), ('wel', 5499), ('goed', 5080), ('contact', 4506), ('medicatie', 3797), ('uur', 3792), ('gaan', 3473), ('kwam', 3463), ('kamer', 3447), ('mee', 3278), ('gesprek', 2978)] 

df = pd.DataFrame(example_list, columns=['word', 'frequency'])
df.plot(kind='bar', x='word')
```

[image]